# How do I meditate?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I just stumbled upon a bunch of wolves, and while I defeated them, I really have to regenerate my health now. The tutorial explained that I can do that by meditating, but I can't find any way to actually meditate in the controller scheme.

How do I meditate? Can I do that anywhere, or are there any restrictions on it?

Comment: A better way to regenerate health is to eat food. There is also a perk that causes food regeneration to last for 20 (real-world) minutes, giving you basically constant regeneration.

Answer (score 9):

The Medidation Menu is on the Far Right of the Menu.

**There are two menus.**

One is a menu where you can save game, load game, exit, etc..

The other is where you have your World Map, Inventory and the Meditation Menu. It's on the **Far Right** of this Menu.

You can see it here in this image:

[image: Meditation Menu]

You can then select the ***span of time*** (You can see the current time you're on and select When you want the meditation to end.) and it will fast-forward to that chosen time healing you in the process.

If you're playing in higher difficulties (Any above *"Story and Sword"*) you will not heal during meditation but the game will always warn you about that.

Comment: I tried doing that and the game prompts : "You cannot do that now." Why is it so?

Comment: it depends. Where are you? are you in combat?

Comment: I think I was on a horse and so I was stopped. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 4):

It's on your main menu, press the touch pad (that's on ps4) it's the last option on the right, choose how much time you'll meditate, remember it only refills your vitality if your on the normal difficulty which is "Story and Sword!" or the easy one "Just the Story!"

Answer (score 2):

On the computer, press backspace and then click on meditation.

Comment: Or 'N' as a default shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Another way to meditate is by pressing "X" (xbox) on the screen that allows you to change the sign you're casting. To meditate you must not be in combat, and standing still.