# I can't meditate!

Tags: xbox-one, the-witcher-3

So I'm playing The Witcher 3 for a while. I used to meditate a lot

Then suddenly now each time I try to meditate the games says "You cannot do this now".

I had this problem for 7 days

- I'm not in combat
- I'm not on water
- I'm not riding a horse
- I even finished all the quest that I had when the problem first showed up

I have tried fast travel, leaving the village, even disconnect the Xbox from power. Nothing works.

Comment: possible duplicates :
- http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219926/how-do-i-meditate 
- http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220657/why-cant-i-meditate

Comment: Are you in a city? You cannot meditate, as far as I know, in zones where your movement is also restricted. This includes, for example, major settlements.

Comment: you cannot meditate in certain locations and scenarios, like you stated above. if you are in a prolonged quest, like being in the castle early on, you cannot meditate there...hopefully you did not spend 7 days in there...

Comment: @Eric You can, but not shortly after you fast traveled for example.

Answer (score -3):

You have to be on Just the Story or Sword and Story to meditate and regenerate health AFAIK.